# How to see the Predefined Variables in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-pipelines-tasks

I want to see the values that is path of predefined variable like for `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` i want to see value stored in it.
I am unable to find this variable value so where can i find it in Azure devops.

In simple words, how could i check what was the Build.SourcesDirectory or Build.Repository.LocalPath used in that particular release pipeline?

Comment: The easiest way is to print them out in the script tasks as  @Krzysztof answered below.

Comment: Any other way ? @LeviLu-MSFT

Comment: You can also task [Display all variables](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.DisplayAllVariables&targetId=72d0c402-3bd0-4b8a-b56c-1ed5cade77d0) in your pipeline.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I am unable to see system variables there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure if you find a specific place in Azure DevOps what values are behind. Values may differ a bit depending in which OS you select for your agent. However you can alwasy print them out. Please check [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

```
steps:
  - bash: echo $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

To print all variables you can use this step (since variables are also available to scripts through environment variables)

```
 steps: # 'Steps' section is to be used inside 'job' section.
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'env | sort'
```

[image]

Another option which works for Windows and Linux would be (all credits to Joe):

```
- pwsh: (gci  env:* | sort-object name)
```

You can also use third party extension [Print all variables](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.printAllVariables)

```
  - task: printAllVariables@1
    displayName: 'Print all variables via extension'
```

Or expression like:

```
  - ${{ each var in variables }}:
    - pwsh: Write-Host "${{ var.Key }} - ${{ var.Value }}"
      displayName: 'Print variables via expression in the loop'
```

Here is an example pipeline:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none

name: Display pipeline variables

variables:
- group: DisplayPipelineVariables
- name: DB_HOSTNAME
  value: 10.123.56.222
- name: DB_PORTNUMBER
  value: 1521
- name: USERNAME
  value: TEST
- name: PASSWORD
  value: TEST
- name: SCHEMANAME
  value: SCHEMA  
- name: ACTIVEMQNAME
  value: 10.123.56.223
- name: ACTIVEMQPORT
  value: 8161

pool:
  vmImage: $(imageName)

jobs:
- job: AllEnvironmentVariables
  strategy:
    matrix:
      linux:
        imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
      mac:
        imageName: 'macOS-latest'
      windows:
        imageName: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - script: env | sort
    displayName: Display all environment variables

- job: PipelineVariablesViaExtension
  strategy:
    matrix:
      linux:
        imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
      mac:
        imageName: 'macOS-latest'
      windows:
        imageName: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - task: printAllVariables@1
    displayName: 'Print all variables via extension'

- job: PipelineVariablesViaExpression
  strategy:
    matrix:
      linux:
        imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
      mac:
        imageName: 'macOS-latest'
      windows:
        imageName: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - pwsh: Write-Host "${{ convertToJson(variables) }}"
    displayName: 'Print all variables via expression'

- job: PipelineVariablesViaExpressionInLoop
  strategy:
    matrix:
      linux:
        imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
      mac:
        imageName: 'macOS-latest'
      windows:
        imageName: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - ${{ each var in variables }}:
    - pwsh: Write-Host "${{ var.Key }} - ${{ var.Value }}"
      displayName: 'Print variables via expression in the loop'
```

Comment: No worries. All things above will work for you. I just mentioned this that value may differ depending OS.

Comment: This works on the cloud but not when I use my local machine as a build agent, even though I have bash installed on it (Windows 10).   It just says, "'c:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe' failed with exit code 4294967295".   Is there some sort of powershell equivalent of this?

Comment: Answering my own question in a comment:  This powershell script works for both:

`- pwsh: (gci  env:* | sort-object name)`

Answer (score -1):

Simpler answer:

```
  - bash: |
      env | sort
    displayName: 'Debug: Show Env Vars'
```

Comment: The existing answer already says this.