# Trying to copy folder from release pipeline to Azure BLOB ended up with no content copied but task is successfully completed

Tags: azure, jmeter, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azcopy

Try to copy JMeter report to AZ BLOB container.

Using Ubunto agent in release pipeline ,as the Azure blob file copy only supported from Win agent i've tried to find some other way to do the copy on a linux agent.

Running the following command in Azure CLI task:

```
azcopy copy '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Report' 'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container?sp=racwdl&st=2021-04-22T12:12:49Z&se=2022-06-01T20:12:49Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&sig=xxxx' --recursive=true
```

I want to copy all the content of folder 'Report' to the AZ BLOB recursively.

The task is finished successfully but no files at all were copied.
Using SAS for the container.

Attached the task logs of running.

Any ideas?

[image: Task logs]

Comment: Can you check if the `Reports` folder is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did not put the files into a wrong path for `Reports` folder. You can check your variable for `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` variable [under Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905758/where-is-system-defaultworkingdirectory-set-for-builds-in-tfs2015) or [print it out under pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135431/how-to-see-the-predefined-variables-in-azure-devops).

With all the steps, you should make sure the files are in the right directory.

**Besides**, you could use the variable [system.debug: true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops#configure-verbose-logs) to check the detailed log about your task.